# Where to find this kind of bolt?

Tags: bolts

We have a system of shelves that we brought with us when we moved to a new apartment now. However, some of the bolts broke and now we're having a hard time buying new ones. These are not from Ikea.

Please see the image below.

The length is about 1 cm and is used to support some other metal holder below the shelf. I can provide more exact measurements or pictures if need be, but somehow I'm not able to find anything that looks like it in stores or online.

Thanks.

*EDIT*:

I do apologize about the low quality of the first image, it's all I had at the time. Now that I'm home, here are some more pictures of: 1) the initial bolt I was asking about 2) The thing it is supposed to support, installed already on the shelf. 3) Another type of screw of this system whose head I do not recognize.

Pictures of 1)
[image]
[image]

Pictures of 2)
[image]
Pictures of 3)
[image]

Comment: Come on. You can do better than that photo. I believe in you.

Comment: Take it outdoors or into bright light to shoot the pic. Light is an essential ingredient in photos, cameras can't see nearly as well as we can.

Comment: Also provide a pic that gives us an idea of what the job of this fastener is to be, so we can offer alternatives.

Comment: Try looking for Deco screws. They look similar to yours.  When you repost your photo lay it next to a ruler so the community will have a sense of scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the pin or dowel that go to a cam lock for furniture.

[Here](https://belleandtheyank.ecrater.com/c/1783430/cam-lock-dowel-pins) is website i found  that has some. If you do not it find there you can check in the furniture parts drawers at you local hardware store or search for furniture parts online.

You will need to measure its length, i would think most are going to be classified in the metric system,  mm or cm.

Keywords: cam lock dowel or pin, Quickfit Style Dowel Pin Cam Lock Fasteners Furniture Connectors

Comment: Thank you, seems like it's this 20mm thing here: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/20mm-Thread-Cam-Lock-Alloy-Shelf_60791356574.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.77.44f426378J9kKx